# CalDav Implementation Using Baïkal

Tags: caldav

I have Installed Baïkal ( http://baikal.codr.fr/ ) at My local server and added user in that.

When I tring to access url for calDav

BASE_URL/sabre/cal.php/

Then its asking for user authentication, after entering correct username and password.

Its giving me following error:

```
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
<s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotImplemented</s:exception>
<s:message>GET is only implemented on File objects</s:message>
<s:sabredav-version>1.8.0</s:sabredav-version>
</d:error>
```

I have searched for this error solution and Baïkal documentation but didn't get success.

can some one guide me how i need to access CalDav url from android phone and iphone to get their calendar events.

Thanks Alot !!

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to happen. CALDAV does not use GETs, it uses PROPFIND, OPTIONS and REPORT. The instructions for getting the CALDAV URL for iOS (iPhone) are in the INSTALL.md file found here: https://github.com/jeromeschneider/Baikal/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Instructions from that file for iOS:

- in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > Add an account > Other
- Select "CalDAV"
- Server: http://dav.mydomain.com/cal.php/principals/jerome
- username: the username you just created (in our example, jerome)
- password: the password you just defined

Comment: Thank you so much, spent 3 hours looking for the solution!